# Subquery in SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I am using `MySQL` and I have two tables. One has the reference to the values and the other has the real values. I want to calculate the `SUM`.

**ItemMess**

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| ID | ItemID | MessType | TimeStamp           |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:53:33 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 2  | 2      | 2        | 2015-04-26 18:54:42 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:54:49 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 4  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:55:01 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 5  | 2      | 2        | 2015-04-26 18:55:04 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

**MessTypes**

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| MessTypeID | MessTypeName | MessTypeValue |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1          | Mess Up      | 1             |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2          | Mess Down    | -1            |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

So if you see, the `MessTypeID` refers to the values in the `MessTypes` table. I want the `sum` of the `up` and `down`. So if I do a query like:

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT `MessTypeValue` FROM `MessTypes` WHERE `MessTypeID`=`MessType`
) AS `Val` FROM `ItemMess` GROUP BY `ItemID`
```

I get this output:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| ID | ItemID | MessType | TimeStamp           |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:53:33 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 2  | 2      | 2        | 2015-04-26 18:54:42 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:54:49 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 4  | 2      | 1        | 2015-04-26 18:55:01 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 5  | 2      | 2        | 2015-04-26 18:55:04 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

But if I give either:

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT `MessTypeValue` FROM `MessTypes` WHERE `MessTypeID`=`MessType`
) AS `Val`, SUM(SELECT `MessTypeValue` FROM `Messtypes` WHERE `MessTypeID`=`MessType`) AS `Mess`FROM `ItemMess` GROUP BY `ItemID`
```

Or

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT `MessTypeValue` FROM `MessTypes` WHERE `MessTypeID`=`MessType`
) AS `Val`, SUM(`Val`) AS `Mess`FROM `ItemMess` GROUP BY `ItemID`
```

I get the following errors:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'SELECT `MessTypeValue` FROM `messtypes` WHERE `MessTypeID`=`MessType`) FROM `' at line 1

And

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'Val' in 'field list'

How do I handle this. I want the `SUM` of the values. Is there any way, that I can replace the `1` and `2` as in the `IDs` with their original values? ps: I don't want to create a view for the whole thing or use `Joins`.

Comment: Can you post what your expected output is?

Comment: @pala_ The sum of values.

Comment: Why is the use of joins disallowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use joins:

```
select im.ItemID, sum(mt.MessTypeValue) as val
from ItemMess im
join MessTypes mt on im.MessTypeID = mt.MessTypeID
group by im.ItemID
```

Without joins:

```
select  im.ItemID, (select sum(mt.MessTypeValue) from MessTypes mt where im.MessTypeID = mt.MessTypeID) as val
from ItemMess im
group by im.ItemID
```

Comment: Any possibility without using joins?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: There might be, but if there is, it's almost certain to be slower and more complicated. This is what joins are for; why would you want to do this without them, anyway?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, sure there are. I have added one.

Comment: @pala_, what is your problem? Which is different name? ItemID, MessTypeID? Or may be MessTypeValue?

Comment: `im.MessTypeID` was different. i just plugged it into my fiddle and spouted off before i actually checked if it was just a field naming issue. like i said. ignore

Comment: Will have a look through!

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something or is all you are looking for this?

```
select i.id, sum(messtypevalue) 
  from itemmess i
    inner join messtypes t
      on i.messtype = t.messtypeid
  group by i.itemid;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5b7d/5)

This would give an output of:

```
ID  |  sum(messtypevalue)
 1  |   1
```

Comment: Any possibility without using joins?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: I am afraid of Joins... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT `i`.`id`,
       Sum(`messtypevalue`)
FROM   `itemmess` AS `i`
       INNER JOIN `messtypes` AS `t`
               ON `i`.`messtype` = `t`.`messtypeid`
GROUP  BY `i`.`itemid`;
```